# ¿Como realizar una actualizacion diaria automatica en mi base de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, modelorelacional

Estoy realizando un programa para un gimnasio el cual funciona con planes de entrenamiento,cada plan tiene una cierta cantidad de clases mensuales y un gimnasta puede inscribirse en cero o muchos planes de entrenamiento.

Cada gimnasta posee un estado de alta o baja, dependiendo de si esta activo en algun plan (no se le vencieron sus planes o cuenta con asistencias en alguno de ellos).

Ademas el gimnasta puede pagar planes por adelantado.

El programa debe realizar diariamente una revision verificando de que gimnastas poseen un plan o planes vencido o sin asistencias (y darlo de baja en caso de que suceda) y si pago meses por adelantado acreditarsele un nuevo mes.

¿Como armo la consulta para realizar la revision diaria?¿Debo recorrer una por una la tabla 'clientes'?

Estoy usando MySQL como motor

Gimnastas = Clientes

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]